# Mongo db different versions

Tags: mongodb, versions

I fount two different Mongo db versions in mongodb forum. I couldnt relate the two versions. Can you kindly help us to identify that.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/release-notes/3.0/ - 3.0.12(9th May 2016)
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/ - 3.2.6(28th Apr 2016)

Comment: I don't understand the question - what is difficult to understand about the existence of different software versions?

Comment: I don't think it is difference existence of Mongodb. The latest Mongo version 3.0.12 in one forum and 3.2.6 in another forum . Is that something Community or Enterprise version or is some other thing identify the different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

I am new to mongodb , when i search latest mongo version i got the above confusion.

Then i understand , Mongo has 2.X,3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3 major versions . In the major version mongo has minor versions like 3.0.12,3.26 .

And the main reason for the confusion is 3.0.12 released on May 9 , 2016 and 3.2.6 release on Apr 28,2016.

I hope any one of beginners would have face this confusion.